# Too large XLXS file in Python

Tags: python, excel, file

I am loading a very large XLXS file in Python. Code: (picture attached)

```
import openpyxl
import pandas as pd

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\nhit\PycharmProjects\Test\WIPAR Reconciliation 2020.xlsx', read_only = True)
print(wb.sheetnames)
```

[XLXS too large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7J79.png)

In[*] appears all times (picture attached). I am wondering if there is a solution for this?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the exact error message, and on which line is it raised?

Comment: Hi, there is no error. It is because the file is too large. In Jupyter notebook, instead of In[1], In[2] etc, it is In[*] because the code takes time to be executed. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Do you have any better way to parse XLXS file from a folder?

Comment: You have already used the `read_only` flag, so I cannot imagine a better option with `openpyxl`. Maybe you could try to export the relevant sheets to csv files, and then read them with `read_csv` which explicitely supports chunking. Anyway, what is the typical size of your *huge* file?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error when trying to open a xlsx workbook on an old office installation (in my case back then it was Office 2013). The old Office versions have a sheet and line limit which is if i remind correctly in the 65000 Range. If your xlsx you try to open exceeds that it will have problems opening.

Comment: Hmm..., `openpyxl` never use any Office installation. It is intended to be able to manage xlsx files on platforms where Microsoft Office cannot run.

Comment: Hi 4lexKidd, Do you have any better way to parse XLXS file from a dictionary?

Comment: Sorry never used openpyxl but directly implemented microsoft foundations classes where i also ran into those "xlsx too large" problems. If openpyxl avoids using an office installation the same error could be occuring due to how openpyxl handles the xlsx and xls formats. Would need some further checking on this site. Note xlsx format is the newer excel format that supports the larger sizes. Nhi Yen you could try exporting the same excel as an xls file and try again. If it works you quite surely have a xls/xlsx handling problem.

Comment: " directly implemented microsoft foundations classes where i also ran into those "xlsx too large" problems" Could you suggest more from this?

Comment: There is a collection of classes called MFC (Microsoft Foundations Classes) which consist of a largly build api including classes to use for handling the Microsoft Office products (like Excel or Word). I sadly don't know if there are python versions of these MFC classes but in C++ i allready used those. They are somewhat tricky to get used to but after that you control nearly everything remotely in Excel and Word. I had a short check and it seams MFC only consist of C++ classes. So you would either have to rely on third party editing packages like openpyxl or build a python wrapper around MFC.